# Regex to match all lines after a specific string

Tags: regex

Possible duplicate of [Regex - find all lines after a match:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628146/regex-find-all-lines-after-a-match) although my need is a little different.

I want to parse a plain text file with multiple date/value data separated by specific strings. I want to skip the first half of the file until a specific line where I want to match the results.

Here is an example of the file in question (including the mess with tabulations and spaces):

```
   I dont want to capture the following measures. This  text is     on a single line and        contains tabs and spaces    is also ends with this token : Token1
05/01/1969         0.01846  
15/01/1969         0.16730  
25/01/1969         0.33988  
05/04/1969         0.81319  
15/04/1969         0.76973  
25/11/2011             0.24210
05/12/2011             0.25220
15/12/2011             0.31160
25/12/2011             0.36845
            End :  bla bla bla
   This text        is also on a single line        and marks the beginning of a new series of      results. These are the results that I want. it also ends with the following         token : Token2
05/01/1969       109.46333  
15/01/1969       110.06998       118.18000
25/01/1969       110.82954  
05/02/1969       111.51394       118.83000
25/02/1969       112.36483  
05/10/2011       114.38798       114.31000
05/10/2011           114.31000       114.38798       114.38798       114.38798       114.38798       114.38798       114.38798
25/12/2011           112.64000       112.41261       112.86301       113.25494       114.06421       115.93219       116.38780
05/01/2012               112.22834       112.92301       113.40561       114.78823       116.62931       117.43421
05/09/2012               110.01410       112.16391       112.88199       115.23640       117.04756       118.04632
15/09/2012               109.97572       112.00809       112.70266       114.91247       116.65256       117.57412
25/09/2012               109.93967       111.87272       112.53305       114.60381       116.26935       117.12756 
            End :  Marks the    end of          the      file
```

What I wish to do is to match every line **after** the line which ends with `Token2`. I have tried different solutions from the other similar questions but none work. I ended up matching all the results of the file and considered splitting it before applying the following pattern. Is there a pure regex solution to this ?

Here is the pattern that works for the whole file. With named capture groups :

```
(?P<date>\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d)\s*(?P<simul>\d+\.*\d*)[\t ]*(?P<observ>\d+\.*\d*){0,1}[\t ]*(?P<prev_no_rain>\d+\.*\d*){0,1}[\t ]*(?P<prev_10_dry>\d+\.*\d*){0,1}[\t ]*(?P<prev_20_dry>\d+\.*\d*){0,1}[\t ]*(?P<prev_50>\d+\.*\d*){0,1}[\t ]*(?P<prev_20_wet>\d+\.*\d*){0,1}[\t ]*(?P<prev_10_wet>\d+\.*\d*){0,1}
```

Regex101 link : https://regex101.com/r/a0mCZ2/3

Comment: What is the regex flavor/tool/programming language where you use it?

Comment: Try [this one with `\G`](https://regex101.com/r/PrbuBO/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may leverage the `\G` operator that matches the start of string (that can be excluded with a negative lookaround) and the end of the previous successful match position. With the `(?:\G(?!\A)|\bToken2[\r\n]+)` we can tell the regex engine to find a whole word `Token2` at the end of the line (with linebreak symbols) and then only find the following subpatterns if they follow in an immediate succession.

A regex that can be used:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)[\r\n]*|Token2[\r\n]+)\K(?P<date>\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\s*(?P<simul>\d+\.*\d*)[\t ]*(?P<observ>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_no_rain>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_10_dry>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_20_dry>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_50>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_20_wet>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_10_wet>\d+\.*\d*)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PrbuBO/2). Note I replaced `{0,1}` with `?` to shorten it a bit.

The part you are interested in is `(?:\G(?!\A)[\r\n]*|Token2[\r\n]+)\K`.

- `(?:\G(?!\A)[\r\n]*|Token2[\r\n]+)` -  1 of two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!\A)[\r\n]*` - end of the previous successful match and 0+ linebreak symbols
  - `|` - or
  - `Token2[\r\n]+` - `Token2` followed with 1+ CR or LFs. (If you need to match `Token2` as a whole word, you might add `\b` before it).
- `\K`  - omit the text matched so far.

The `(?P<date>\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\s*(?P<simul>\d+\.*\d*)[\t ]*(?P<observ>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_no_rain>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_10_dry>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_20_dry>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_50>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_20_wet>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?P<prev_10_wet>\d+\.*\d*)?` is your pattern that I did not modify too much, and that matches a line with specific fata (note that the fact it matches a line justifies the usage of `[\r\n]*` after `(\G(?!\A))`).

Comment: Well you're awesome. I've never heard of the \G operator. To answer to your first comment on the original question, I plan to use this pattern with .NET which doesn't seem to know the \K operator, but the regex still works without it.

Comment: Yes, the `\K` is not supported in .NET. It supports `\G`, but you can also leverage an infinite width lookbehind. Just use your regex and pre-pend it with `(?<=\bToken2[\r\n]+.*?)`: `(?s)(?<=\bToken2[\r\n]+.*?)(?<date>\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\s*(?<simul>\d+\.*\d*)[\t ]*(?<observ>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?<prev_no_rain>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?[\t ]*(?<prev_10_dry>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?<prev_20_dry>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?<prev_50>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?<prev_20_wet>\d+\.*\d*)?[\t ]*(?<prev_10_wet>\d+\.*\d*)?`

Comment: I understand the regex in its entirety now, except for one piece, which doesn't seem to serve any purpose: `(?!\A)`. That's asserting a condition which will be true 100% of the time, and is thus pointless, correct?

Comment: The `(?!\A)` is a negative lookahead that restricts the `\G` to only match at the positions after the previous successful match. Else, it would also match at the start of the string, and all the subsequent matches would be anchored at the start of the string.

Comment: Ahhh, I just figured that out. Didn't see your comment soon enough. Very well done.